# How do I resolve this firebase import error? Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to import auth from my firebase.js file but when I type `import {auth} from "./firebase"` I get this error:

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './firebase' in 'C:\Users\Zahraa\projects\netflix-build\src\Screens'**

and when I try `import {auth} from "../firebase"` I get this error:

**Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package C:\Users\Zahraa\projects\netflix-build\node_modules\firebase (see exports field in C:\Users\Zahraa\projects\netflix-build\node_modules\firebase\package.json)
Did you mean './firebase'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, C:\Users\Zahraa\projects\netflix-build\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too**.

I am unsure what the problem is. this is my firebase.js code:

```
 import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDMFs_i60UUWNutBKJVzBkZ2U5W93JCnoM",
  authDomain: "netflix-clone-18cc6.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "netflix-clone-18cc6",
  storageBucket: "netflix-clone-18cc6.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1000960928424",
  appId: "1:1000960928424:web:e10790f27d2d1fa9b1f09d",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db =
  firebaseApp.firestore(); 
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { auth };
export default db;
```

Comment: Have you tried like this : import firebase from "firebase/app"; and  import "firebase/auth";

Answer (score 0):

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDMFs_i60UUWNutBKJVzBkZ2U5W93JCnoM",
  authDomain: "netflix-clone-18cc6.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "netflix-clone-18cc6",
  storageBucket: "netflix-clone-18cc6.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1000960928424",
  appId: "1:1000960928424:web:e10790f27d2d1fa9b1f09d",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db =
  firebaseApp.firestore(); 
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  export auth = getAuth(app)

export default db;
```

Comment: first, initialize the application with the firebase initializeApp library then use getAuth function from firebase. I hope this helps you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).